# How to denote the element of the domain minimising a function

Tags: notation

For example, consider the function $f(x) = |x|+1$

If I used $\operatorname{min}_{x\in\mathbb R}(f(x))$ in a formula, I understand I would be talking about the real number $f(x) = 1$, since that it the minimum value of the function.
But say instead I wanted to talk about the real number $x=0$, since that is the element minimizing the function $f$, how would I do this? Is there any standard notation? Or do I need to just define this in words?

Comment: Sometimes $x^*$ is used to denote an minimizer(optimizer).

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max#Arg_min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ${\arg\min}_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x)$

Comment: Be aware that formally, this is a set, since there could be multiple minimizers. Still, we usually just treat it as a number if the minimum is unique.